# DJI Mobile SDK - how is distance between adjacent waypoints calculated?

Tags: dji-sdk

Using the DJI Mobile SDK to upload Waypoint Missions, if two adjacent waypoints are determined by the DJI to be too close (within 0.5 meters), the upload is rejected.

Does anyone know the algorithm used to determine the distance between adjacent waypoints in a waypoint mission?

Specifically, is the DJI algorithm using a haversine calculation for distance between lat, lon coordinates and if so, what is the earth radius used? Is it the UIGG mean radius: 6371008.8 meters. Or some other radius?

Or does it use the ellipsoidal Vincenty formula (WGS-84)?

This information would be useful for more precise waypoint decimation prior to mission upload.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would comment that DJI answering an internal implementation question is very unlikely since it would expose them to having to support the implementation over time and across aircraft.  Different aircraft, different technologies may result in varying implementations.

What has always worked for me it to use standard "distance between points" calculations, either common from map formulas or as built into platform SDK (iOS, Android, etc.)  I have found these to be sufficiently accurate enough to plan even complex flights.

Answer (score 0):

Based on several tests I can now confirm that the current DJI internal distance computation is dependent on latitude and/or longitude. Meaning that you will get different results for the same (!) waypoint distance pair depending on where your two points are anchored.

A 1.5-meter distance Waypoint Pair got accepted as a mission in a location in central Europe but were rejected with WAYPOINT_DISTANCE_TOO_CLOSE for a location in the central US.

(We verified with https://gps-coordinates.org/distance-between-coordinates.php that both waypoint distance pairs had the same 1.5 meter distance between them.)

So it's safe to assume that DJI has a bug in their distance calculation.